# Unable to load data correctly in Jupyter Notebook - Not sure what the issue is

Tags: jupyter-notebook, read.csv

I am trying to load a csv dataset using Pandas but I cannot seem to separate the columns and data in order to start working with the data. I have tried various methods but still cannot get to load it correctly

Below is my code:

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

%matplotlib inline

np.random.seed(0)

car_data = pd.read_csv("Cars93.csv", sep=",").replace('"','', regex=True)

My output is the following:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c05pI.png)

I have tried using:

pd.read_csv('Cars93.csv').replace('"', '')

And:

df_csv = pd.read(path_to_file,delimiter=',')

But I still cannot get the data to seperate. Below is a screenshot of the dats

[Cars93 Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLR3m.png)

Comment: if you data file is a csv file, you don't need `.replace('"','', regex=True)`.  you'd better provide csv file rather than a screenshot

Comment: Thanks Ryan, managed to figure it out, the below code worked:

Comment: car_data = pd.read_csv('Cars93.csv',sep='["]*,["]*', engine='python')

car_data.columns = car_data.columns.str.strip('"')
car_data.iloc[:, [0,-1]] = car_data.iloc[:, [0,-1]].apply(lambda x: x.str.strip('"'))

Comment: Please format your code block(s), logs and errors, in order to make your question more readable, and receive better quality answers. For more information, take a look on this link: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks